# Xcode 4, OCUnit and NSLog

Tags: xcode4, nslog, ocunit

I'm kind of puzzled by the following: I'm making use of OCUnit in an iPhone static library project. Why can't I see the NSLog output in the debug area? Is there a way to fix it? I can see the NSLog output just fine in the system console, but switching back and forth gets annoying after a while (or perhaps I should just get a 2nd screen).

**Edit:** I guess the reason I don't see NSLog output in the debugger is because *otest* runs the tests - this is the reason why the system console mentions *otest* as source for the NSLog output. Still would be nice if there was a way to somehow see this output in the debugger.